# Filament that is resistant to ozone

Tags: filament, fdm, filament-choice

Does a filament exist that can resist ozone (like certain silicone tubing's can). Most glass bottles come with tin or plastic screw hard tops and I would like to replace the screw caps with something that is more resistant to ozone.

The reason for this is I make my own homemade ozonated oil in glass bottles and I would like to print out different hard screw top caps for some of the bottles.

Comment: What about a coating? Either for your original tops or your 3d printed replacements.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE It could work.  The original screw cap has completely fallen apart and rusted.  But if I print another screw cap with PLA / PETG and coat that part it could also work (as long as the screw cap can be closed)

Comment: You can also use a protective foil between the screw cap and the bottle. Just be sure it doesn't get torn when you screw/unscrew, but since it could be made of plastic, it shouldn't happen.

Comment: If plastic caps don't work out for you, you can get glass reagent bottles with glass stoppers.

Comment: You cannot 3D print it but you can make a gasket out of cork. It will hold well. And you can use any cap for that, just cut a round disk out of 2-3 mm cork. https://websealinc.com/technical-info/additional-materials/cork-gaskets/ Do not use PLA-cork filament, PLA does not resist to ozone. Or just use a normal cork from wine bottles...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If making your own caps ends up being the best solution, TPU (thermoplastic polyurethane) is probably your best bet. I don't have specific information on printed TPU filament and ozone, but TPU is widely regarded as one of the most chemical-resistant materials you can easily print with, and [this page by Ozone Solutions](https://ozonesolutions.com/blog/ozone-compatible-materials/) rates polyurethane (no mention of specific types) A/Excellent described as:

> Ozone has **no effect** on these materials. They will last indefinitely.

Being at least slightly flexible, TPU will also yield a good seal without any additional gasket. You should probably choose an unpigmented "natural/clear" TPU filament in case the pigments do react.

It might (probably would) also work to coat an existing cap with polyurethane. I'm not sure how you'd best get it to adhere, but lightly sanding the plastic then using a spray in multiple coats is what I'd try first.

Answer (score 2):

This is highly relevant: PETG is very resistant to Ozone.

https://www.plasticsintl.com/chemical-resistance-chart

Comment: Link only answer. Please [edit] and add the chart to your answer. If the link dies your question won't be of much use to others.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.calpaclab.com/polyetherether-ketone-peek-chemical-compatibility-chart/ and https://www.polyfluor.nl/en/chemical-resistance/peek/ PEEK is very resistant to ozone.

PEEK does cost about as much per gram as silver.

Comment: PEEK also requires a printer capable of temperatures over 370°C, which tend to be quite expensive or extensive mods to an inexpensive printer.

Comment: Does that make anything in my post inaccurate?

Comment: No, just likely less useful to OP and other readers.